# Classification of covering spaces - Hatcher pag 63

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading the section about Classification of Covering Spaces of Hatcher, and at the end of the second paragraph I read "In particular we can ask whether the trivial subgroup realizes".

It is not clear to me why this is enough. Can anyone explain this? Thank you

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Can you fix your question? As is, it most likely will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the quote is incorrect. It should be

> In particular we can ask whether the trivial subgroup **is realized**

Which may or may not make it clearer.

Essentially, there is a correspondence between (subgroups of the fundamental group of a space $X$) and (covers of $X$). Chapter 2 of Hatcher studies this correspondence, and in particular answers the following question:

> Does every subgroup of the fundamental group correspond to some cover?

The trivial subgroup is a cover, so the question "does the trivial subgroup of the fundamental group correspond to a cover?" is a particular case of the main question. This is the contents of the second paragraph on page 63.

---

If you are asking **why** this is true, you will need to read the chapter! It is too long a story to explain (well) in a single stackexchange post. If you could ask a more specific question, we'd be able to give a more specific answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I was asking "why this is true", because from the way it's written it seems something trivial that the reader should just notice. I'm going to read the chapter. Thanks again!